# Restriction of Differential Form On a Connected and Compact Submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, submanifold

Show that, conversely, if $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a compact and connected submanifold with the proper
$$
\left.(x d x+y d y+z d z)\right|_M=0,
$$
then $M$ is one of the spheres centered at the origin.

My attempt: Consider a smooth function $f(x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ such that $(i^*df)_p = (df|_M)_p(V_p) = 0, \forall V_p \in T_p M$. If such $f$ does exists, then $df|_M = \sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial f}{dx^i} dx^i = x dx + y dy + z dz = 0$ and I can integrate to get the defining equation for the sphere. But I don't know how to prove the existence of such $f$. Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is _submanifold_ intended to be read (perhaps because of unstated context from a problem statement) as _surface_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking it: since $M$ is connected, ${\rm d}(x^2+y^2+z^2)|_M = (x\,{\rm d}x+y\,{\rm d}y+z\,{\rm d}z)|_M=0$ means that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is constant on $M$ so, when $M$ is a surface, it must also be an open subset of the sphere $S$ of corresponding radius. Then compactness of $M$ says that it is also closed in $S$, and then connectedness of $S$ yields $M=S$.

If we do not assume that $M$ is a surface, there are counter-examples (such as a point, or a great circle).

Comment: I don’t see why $M$ is open in the sphere. Consider a singleton $M$ which is not the origin. This is compact, connected, and 0-dimensional so every 1-form (in particular $x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz$) vanishes, yet $M$ is obviously not equal to a sphere of positive radius. Constancy of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ seems only to imply that $M$ is contained in the sphere of corresponding radius.

Comment: oh and we could also take $M$ to be a great circle, so we also have a 1D counterexample. So, at the very least we should assume $M$ is a compact, connected, 2-dimensional submanifold. But now we’re set because $M$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^3$ which is contained in the submanifold $S$ of $\Bbb{R}^3$, and hence (with a little definition chasing) $M$ is a submanifold of $S$. Since their dimensions match, it follows $M$ is open in $S$. Now, the rest of the argument goes through.

Comment: @peek-a-boo You're absolutely right, I'll update the answer. I had in my mind that $M$ was a surface throughout all of it (or else why would we restrict ourselves to submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$?).